# Silverlight zoom area with canvas and scrollview

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight

I have simple canvas with items and i need to add for scroll view as parent for my canvas.
But i fased with problem that after set

```
canvas.RenderTransform=new ScaleTransform(){...}
```

Scroolbars not appears or working not correctly.
Will be glad for any information.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The render transform occurs much later in the UI rendering process. It ultimately performs a matrix transform on controls rendering.  The scroll viewer will be completely unware of this transform, its scrollbars will be based on the un-transformed size of the original Canvas.

The silverlight toolkit contains a `LayoutTransformer` control.  This control applies a transform to its content as part of the layout process and reports the post-transform size as its desired size.

Consider this:-

```
    <ScrollViewer Width="200" Height="200" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
        <toolkit:LayoutTransformer>
            <toolkit:LayoutTransformer.LayoutTransform>
                <ScaleTransform ScaleX="2" ScaleY="2" />
            </toolkit:LayoutTransformer.LayoutTransform>
            <Canvas Width="150" Height="150" Background="Aquamarine">
                <Rectangle Fill="Blue" Canvas.Top="10" Canvas.Left="10" Width="30" Height="30" />
            </Canvas>
        </toolkit:LayoutTransformer>
    </ScrollViewer>
```

Whilst the `Canvas` has a size (150) smaller than the containing scroll viewer (200), it is scaled so that it would be larger (300).  The `LayoutTransformer` reports its desired size as 300, the post-transform size of the canvas.  Hence the ScrollViewer displays scroll bars to accomodate it.  Without the benefit of the `LayoutTransformer` the `ScrollViewer` would only see the Canvas as having a size 150 despite any applied RenderTransform.